# How does HDFS stores single data which is larger than the block size?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How hadoop will split the data, in case one of my single data is more than the block size?
Eg. Data(talking about single record) I am storing is of size 80 mb and the block size is 64 mb, so how hadoop manages such scenario?

Answer (score 2):

If we use 64MB of block size then data will be load into only two blocks(64MB and 16MB).Hence the size of metadata is decreased.

Edit:
Hadoop framework divides the large file into blocks (64MB or 128 MB) and stores in the slave nodes. HDFS is unware of the content of the block. While writing the data into block it may happen that the record crosses the block limit and part of same record is written on one block and the other is written on other block.
So, the way Hadoop tracks this split of data is by the logical representation of the data known as Input Split. When Map Reduce client calculates the input splits, it actually checks if the entire record resides in the same block or not. If the record over heads and some part of it is written into another block, the input split captures the location information of the next Block and byte offset of the data needed to complete the record. This usually happens in the multi-line record as Hadoop is intelligent enough to handle the single line record scenario.
Usually, input split is configured same as the size of block size but consider if the input split is larger than the block size. Input split represents the size of data that will go in one mapper. Consider below example
• Input split = 256MB
• Block size = 128 MB
Then, mapper will process two blocks that can be on different machines. Which means to process the block the mapper will have to transfer the data between machines to process. Hence to avoid the unnecessary data movement (data locality) we usually keep the same Input split as block size.

Comment: Not talking about the whole file, rather than just single record(which is 80 mb).

Comment: @NiranjanKumar It gonna process that likewise whether its a file or record .Please refer to my updated answer as I can not post it in comment because of word limits